# How to convert ES6 to ES5 in Cordova through a hook?

Tags: cordova, ecmascript-6

Cordova crosswalk plugin does not work with iOS so the WebView in iOS runs native. The problem is that the native WebView (Safari/UIWebView) does not run ES6 but my project is written in ES6.

I need a kind of "recursive hook" to convert all parts of my project in ES6 to ES5 starting by the command `emulate ios command`.

**obs1** I know there how to install manually Crosswalk in Cordova for iOS, but this alternative would break my project because this WebView is not the same as Chrome and lacks of some APIs.

**obs2** My project does not use ES6 modules, just siimpler features: arrow functions, object ratings, template strings etc ...